# HardHat and Rinkeby ProviderError: Must be authenticated Error

Tags: ethereum, hardhat

When I run

`npx hardhat console --network rinkeby`

`accounts = await ethers.provider.listAccounts();`

I get

**Uncaught ProviderError: Must be authenticated!**

with below rinkeby network config in hardhat.config.js

```
rinkeby: {
  url: "ALCHEMY_URL",
  accounts:["YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY"],
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution: update config file with below lines:

```
rinkeby: {
        url: "ALCHEMY_URL",
        accounts: ["YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY"],
        gas: 2100000,
        gasPrice: 8000000000,
        saveDeployments: true,
    }
```

This works like a charm. Hope this helped in saving some of your time.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, your `hardhat.config.js` should look like this

```js
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');

module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.0',
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
       url: `${ARCHEM_APP_URL}`,
       accounts: [`${ACCOUNT_KEY}`],
       gas: 2100000,
       gasPrice: 8000000000,
       saveDeployments: true,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the same solution as the currently highest-voted answer. Recommendation: edit that answer with your suggestions. You will get credit if the edits are approved.

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue with your provider URL, try it without env first. it will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).